# pkill -u user not working

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, process

I recently switched from CentOS7 to Ubuntu 18.04. I used to be able to pkill -u user and it would kill *all* my processes. However, when I try to do the same in Ubuntu, my SSH session remains active. Using XRDP, I have a similar issue. If I try using "pkill -u user", my XRDP session is terminated and, as root I can see the following process:

```
user  20848     1  0 09:33 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -s
```

However, once that process is there, I cannot log back in via XRDP, and I get a few errors upon login. My only fix is to pkill -u user as root. Once I do that, I am able to use XRDP again.

Regardless, I cannot see that process as "user" using ps but I can kill it if I know the process PID.

Thoughts?

Comment: So your question is why `ssh-agent` is getting orphaned?

Comment: My immediate question is how can I kill all of my processes without having to sudo or switch to root? If I "pkill -u user" as root, it actually kills all the processes of that user but if do the same as that user, it does not (namely, if I have an ongoing XRDP session, that ssh-agent process will remain running, for instance).
Why is the ssh-agent process orphaned *after* "pkill -u user", and is there a way to avoid/fix this, is my other question.

Answer (score 0):

From `man pkill`,

```
   -f, --full
          The pattern is normally only matched against the process name.  When -f is set, the
          full command line is used.
```

So `pgrep --full "/usr/bin/ssh-agent -s"` should show you the PID (then `ps -fp$(pgrep --full "/usr/bin/ssh-agent -s")` for more info.